# How do I get the Google Autofill to return positional information

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am using the google address api to **autofill** an address form.  All I actually want is the **latitude and longitude**.  The api call is working and gives me the address components.  How do I get it to give me the latitude and longitude ?

I can not find any document on what other components it can return.  This is the options portion

```
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

This is the form and code I am using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something similar to this?

http://codepen.io/algib/pen/Kpxzpy

have you looked into calling

```
place.geometry.location.lat();
place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Comment: great! best of luck with your project!